# How do I remove a file when no user has the permissions to do so?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I have a file that was corrupted and needs to be deleted on Windows 10. I can't delete the file as a user with administrative privileges. The built in "Administrator" account can't delete the file either. I've already checked if any process is using the file, no process is using the file.

My user and the "Administrator" user doesn't have Read permissions:

[image]

I can't take ownership of the file as Windows is "unable to display current owner" - see screenshot below. This is the same result when using the built in Administrator account.

[image]

When I click "Continue" or "Change" on the window above, I still can't take ownership:

[image]

How do I delete this file? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with takeown and icacls command?

Comment: `takeown /f WinSCP.exe` results in `ERROR: Access is denied.` and `icacls WinSCP.exe /grant etngu:F /q` results in `WinSCP.exe: Access is denied.` in both my account and the Administrator account.

Comment: Boot into safe mode and then try to delete the file and see if that'll let you remove it. I assume the Programs and Feature and uninstalling WinSCP properly is not an option? Can you explain how this file got corrupted or what you see or noticed that indicates this to you? Were you in the middle of installing and the PC hosed up or something or what is the deal. Maybe adding some of these details will ring a bell for someone. Also, if you add the WinSCP tag your your question, you might hear from [Martin Prikry](https://superuser.com/users/213663/martin-prikryl) the author of WinSCP on it.

Comment: Safe mode worked! If you post it as an answer I'd be willing to accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot into Safe Mode and remove the file.